# Best practice for uninstalling software with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Like a lot of other applications out there the BlueJeans Desktop App MSI comes in two flavours: Per User MSI & Per Machine MSI.

Today, it is possible to have both installed on the same machine, but I have an increasing number of customers who have users with both installed and want to be able to clean it up. I have put together a cleanup script that handles uninstalling our application, but what I need to know from the community is whether I should utilize PowerShell to connect to each machine and run the script remotely or deploy the script via SCCM, IBM BigFix etc. to each machine and run the script locally?

A copy of my script can be found here: https://github.com/stuartminch/powershell/blob/master/cleanup_utility.ps1

Comment: Seems somewhat of question with opinionated answerable , can you rephrase and add details perhaps,

Comment: The question as is seems like a better fit for ServerFault, and I would say best practice without a doubt is SCCM

Comment: Not really a stackoverflow question. Can you move it to Server Vault. Probably, there it will suit

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate MSI installers (User MSI & Per Machine MSI) the easiest way would be to use `MSI {GUID}` to uninstall them.

example `msiexec.exe /x {GUID} /q`

If you have them installed on a machine you can find uninstall string with GUID under

> "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{GUID}\UninstallString

You can then configure it in SCCM.

Best practice would be to configure the deployment along with uninstall so if you deployed it through SCCM just add Uninstall commands there.